# Laravel model attribute returning empty array

Tags: laravel, api, model, resources

I have a model called Address. It has an 'additional' attribute. Although the attribute is filled, the model returns an empty array. I use an API resource to get the data.

This is the Address model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Address extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

      /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'addresses';

    /**
     * The primary key associated with the table.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    /**
     * Indicates if the model's ID is auto-incrementing.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    public $incrementing = true;

    /**
     * Indicates if the model should be timestamped.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    public $timestamps = false;

    /**
     * The database connection that should be used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $connection = 'solarium';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        //
    ];

    /**
    * The attributes that aren't mass assignable.
    *
    * @var array
    */
    protected $guarded = [];

    /**
     * The model's default values for attributes.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $attributes = [
        //
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        //
    ];

    public function addressable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

This is the Address API resource:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use App\Models\Address;
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class AddressResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * The resource that this resource collects.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $collects = Address::class;

    /**
     * Indicates if the resource's collection keys should be preserved.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    public $preserveKeys = true;

    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id'         => $this->id,
            'cep'        => $this->cep,
            'street'     => $this->street,
            'number'     => $this->number,
            'district'   => $this->district,
            'city'       => $this->city,
            'state'      => $this->state,
            'additional' => $this->additional,
        ];
    }
}
```

As I said, the 'additional' attribute returns an empty array although it is filled with a string value.

Comment: Can you also post the model here to see if there is any issue there.

Comment: Just edited the post with the Address model.

Comment: You should remove the unnecessary model properties. You don't need both `protected` and `guarded` for instance.

Answer (score 0):

The `JsonResource` has a public property named `additional` which has a default value of `[]`, an empty array. That is what you are accessing since `$this->additional` is asking for that property. This is not forwarding that access to the model (resource) since this is an accessible property on this instance, (how PHP's OOP works).

You would probably have to access the underlying resource from the property of the `JsonResource` to then access that particular property (attribute):

```
$this->resource->additional
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was still stuck on this issue until this day. hahaha! thanks a lot!

Comment: @EdgardBertelli no problem ... if it solved your problem you can mark this as the accepted answer, if it was useful to you can upvote it if you would like